# Why does a variable given data type "range" still show as "list" when the "type" function is used on it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

While studying data types in Python, I encountered a data type range and used a variable to define it. However using type function to know about this still tells that it's a list data types.

Am I missing something here? Please guide. Thank you so much.

```
x = range(3)
print(type(x))
```

Output is as shown below:

```
C:\Python27>python.exe learn.py
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of the `range` function?

Comment: In Python 2, `range` returned a list. It is a `range` object in Python 3.

Comment: Just started to learn from w3chools basics, would you recommend a best place to get more insight on these data types?

Comment: You should really use Python 3, Python 2 is reaching its end of life, and there really is no reason to start using it now.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, you're right, thank you so much
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> x=range(6)
>>> print(type(x))
<class 'range'>
>>>

And noted on your recommendation to learn version 3

Comment: Also, you can have some ideas of tutorials to read here: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: ``range`` is not a type in Python2.

Comment: Stop with w3schools, the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) should be your first source of documentation. See this section on [Data Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html) and for [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). If you're new, I recommend browsing through the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are mixing up Python 3 and 2. These are two major versions of Python.
Python 3000 introduced many intentionally backwards incompatible changes including in the workings
of the range function.

In Python 2, the range function immediately expanded out to a list 
`list_range = list(range(3))`

In Python 3 it is just a mapping to the range data type.

Check the official docs here [https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html]

It is something to do with memory.

Answer (score 1):

With Python2, range returned the list.

If you try to run your code with python3, it returns the 'range' type as a output of your code.